# WakefulBroadcastReceiver intent not starting only in some cases (strange)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a very strange bug happening in my app. I am building an Alarm APP and I am using SQLite to store alarm data and broadcast receivers to manage the alarm manager calls.

The code of onReceive strangely does not behave in the same way in some cases. I try to start an Activity when the receiver receives a broadcast, nearly 90% of cases everything goes well and I manage to start the Activity, but in some cases strangely enough the receiver executes the instruction "startActivity(i)" but nothing happens.

It is really hard to reproduce the BUG and during my debugging I have learned what I have mentioned, but more than this is really difficult for me to understand how a call to startActivity() in most cases works and in some cases does not work. I have searched through the Stack community but no one seamed to have this kind of problem, everybody just had problems in starting the activity because they had not set the flag or because they had not registered the receiver in the manifest. Below I am posting the code.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Utils.logToFile("Received Alarm ,I am in onReceive(), ALARM ID: "+intent.getExtras().getInt(Constants.ALARM_ID));
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StopAlarm.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(Constants.ALARM_ID, intent.getExtras().getInt(Constants.ALARM_ID));
        if(intent.getExtras().containsKey(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM)){
            b.putString(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM, intent.getExtras().getString(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM));
        }
        i.putExtras(b);
        //this flag is needed to start an Activity from a BroadcastReceiver
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);


        //this method reads from the DB and sets the next alarm
        //I tried commenting this method so that no DB action is 
        //performed and still the bug happened
        setAlarm(context.getApplicationContext());
        //this method just logs data into a file that I have created to keep track of events 
        //since not always the device is connected with LogCat
        Utils.logToFile("Received Alarm, Intent(context, StopAlarm.class);");
    }
```

Do I need to set any other flag and how is it possible that startActivity(intent) behaves incorrectly in some cases?

**EDIT**

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="package.activity.StopAlarm"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" 
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
</activity>

<receiver android:name="package.receivers.AlarmReceiver" />
```

Comment: Please post your activity declaration code from your Manifest, to better understand the issue.

Comment: Just added the manifest. The code works in 90% of the cases, so the  intent starts my activity , but strangely in some cases it does not start it.

Comment: Your code seems fine. The only change i could recommend is using intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) instead of intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK). Also,when the 10% of the time that it fails, is it when you have put the Activity to background by pressing the home button.

Comment: I will try setting the flag by adding it to the intent, so not just setting it. Although most likely it will make much difference, still I will try it hoping that will solve the problem. That 10% in which the bug happens is not only in the case you mentioned. Even if it were the strange thing is that in the same use case the app behaves well 90% of the times but sometimes in that 10% I encounter that bug even if the use case is always the same.

Comment: Now i will try the google way of handling wakefulBroadcasts : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html.

Comment: Tried starting IntentService from the receiver and after that starting the activity i need from the IntentService class. still the bug is there, it worked 5-6 times in a row and after that the 7-th time it failed to start the activity. No message in the LogCat no nothing :( . pretty desperate now.

Comment: You asked : "is it when you have put the Activity to background by pressing the home button" , I find it interesting now to know if that use case in some cases creates the bug. What did you mean to say when you mentioned that?

Comment: set the launch mode of your activity in manifest to android:launchMode="singleTop" and intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) to your intent which starts the activity

Comment: I have solved the issue and I posted the solution. Thank you for your time and effort. I would like to be able to give you points for the effort and the desire to help, how can I do so?

Comment: Its cool. The important thing is you have your solution.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help and the kindness :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally solved the issue by creating an IntentService and by starting the activity from the IntentService and setting two flags to the Intent. After doing this I placed the code which reads from DB in the activity that is started from the IntentService. I have tested nearly 60 times the behaviour and in all the tests the app behaved correctly. I am posting the code below.

```
    public class MyAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        // The app's AlarmManager, which provides access to the system alarm services.
        private static AlarmManager alarmMgr;
        // The pending intent that is triggered when the alarm fires.
        private static PendingIntent alarmIntent;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmIntentService.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt(Constants.ALARM_ID, intent.getExtras().getInt(Constants.ALARM_ID));
            if(intent.getExtras().containsKey(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM)){
                b.putString(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM, intent.getExtras().getString(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM));
            }
            i.putExtras(b);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startWakefulService(context, i);
        }
```

This is the IntentService I needed to implement

```
    public class AlarmIntentService extends IntentService {
        public AlarmIntentService() { 
            super("AlarmIntentService"); 
        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, StopAlarm.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt(Constants.ALARM_ID, intent.getExtras().getInt(Constants.ALARM_ID));
            if(intent.getExtras().containsKey(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM)){
                b.putString(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM, intent.getExtras().getString(Constants.SNOOZE_ALARM));
            }
            i.putExtras(b);
            //THESE ARE THE FLAGS NEEDED TO START THE ACTIVITY AND TO PREVENT THE BUG
            //(CLEAR_TASK is crucial for the bug and new task is needed to start activity from outside of an activity)
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

            startActivity(i);

            MyAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        } 
    }
```

This is the activity started by the IntentService. Here I set the next alarm.

```
public class StopAlarm extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stop_alarm);
        //this method reads from the DB and sets the next alarm
        MyAlarmReceiver.setAlarm(getApplicationContext());
        ...
```

Comment: But Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK destroy's my app business logic(There could be multiple alarm activity). What to do?

Comment: P.S. : Is it necessary:

Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmIntentService.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // necessary???
startWakefulService(context, i);

Comment: This is what you get if you remove the flags. Now I check what happens when just removing Clear_Task
Quoted from Crash Log in AndroidMonitor"android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Comment: i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
I tried it having only this flag and it looks to work as a first test but you would have to test it more to see if it really is ok or if you would run into my old issue. Nonetheless I think it should be ok with only this flag. By the way what do you mean it breaks your business logic

Comment: 1. When I use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK. It clears all the instance of this activity that's open. This scenario is conflicting with my situation(there could be multiple alarm activity opened).


2. i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // necessary??? ->
There you are starting a service not an activity. I think in this case this flag is not necessary.

Comment: I meant that NEW_TASK is needed in the case when starting the activity from the intent service. Meaning remove from that intent only the flag of CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. From my experience the problem is,that startActivity(i) is asynchronous. So in this case the program will simultaneously call activities onCreate(),onStart(), etc. but also call  QlokAlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent) (without waiting for the activity to be closed), which will release the wakeLock. Because of that the device can go to sleep during executing the activities onCreate() or onStart().

Rubin, I know, that my answer is a contradiction of your solution, but my logs clearly indicated such order of events:
- startActivity called
- onCreate of the activity called
- completeWakefulIntent(intent); called in between logs from onStart of the activity

My workaround this is to start a wakelock with a timeout of eg 20 seconds just before calling startActivity and then start another wakeLock in the activities onCreate, which will be released in the onDestroy method.
I'm not sure if my solution goes along with best practises, but I haven't found a better solution so far.